# How to setup RSS feed without access to httpd-conf

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, rss, httpd.conf

I was following a video tutorial on Youtube from phpacademy, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxWYeCGa-PA&index=6&list=WL to make a dynamic RSS feed. In order to do that I need to be able to use php inside my rss file.

In this video the guy mentions adding the following line to the HTTPD-Conf file in order to allow this.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .rss
```

I contacted my web host 123-reg and asked them

> *Do I have access to the HTTPD.Conf file, or is it already configured to allow this.*
> *I am looking to add the following line of code to the file if it isn't already in there.*
>
> *AddType application/x-httpd-php .rss*
>
> *What options do I have?*

They responded with the following

> *The HTTPD.Conf file cannot be accessed with a shared hosting package*
> *as the one used to host the website for the domain vwrx-project.co.uk.*
> *This file is already configured to allow RSS, however you will need to*
> *enable it.   You can try adding the handler into the .htaccess file.*

Does this make any sense to someone, I don't really know what code I should be looking to add into my .htaccess file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more hunting around, and having looked up DaveG's code I wasn't sure it would do as I would have liked.

I have a file with a .rss extension for my rss feed, so from my understanding of the above code, it would redirect you from filnename.rss to filename.php where as what I was looking to do was retain the .rss extension but allow that file to read and interpret the php within it.

After some more searching I found that I could have used the original code from the video, and place it inside my .htaccess file instead on my httpd.conf file, I didn't realize that the code was interchangeable.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .rss  // For older versions of php
```

Anyway whilst looking for this solution I saw some using the line of code below to achieve the same result, the only real difference being it is for PHP5 and later which is whats running on my server so AddType is now AddHandler and we add a 5 to the end of php

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .rss  // For use with PHP5+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use url rewriting (if your hosting supports this) to direct non-existing files and directories, with .rss extension to .php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.rss$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Put all these lines into your `.htaccess` file and `youtubefeed.rss` will open `youtubefeed.php`, which you can program yourself.